# PDO ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean and integer - if empty input

Tags: php, postgresql, dynamic, pdo, boolean

I am using PDO for a dynamical update query for PostgreSQL. The problem is, all the values are transmitted to the database as strings, which throws an error for the supposed boolean (**edit**: and integer) values:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: Â»Â«

**Edit:** The problem appears whenever the boolean or integer fields get an empty input. What can I do to make the PDO transfer the inputs as "null" to the database instead of empty strings that throw the data type errors?

Below is my update method, I have tried to do the binding inside a loop and add an explicit type casting for the two supposed boolean values:

```
public function updateMod($array)
{
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $vals = array_values($array);

    $setStr = "";
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $setStr .= "$key = :$key, ";
    }
    $setStr = rtrim($setStr, ", ");

    $pdoConn = DbConnection::openConnection();
    $stmt = $pdoConn->prepare("UPDATE mods SET $setStr WHERE id = :id;");

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        // type casting the two supposed booleans:
        if($key === 'g_exists' || $key === 'w_exists') {
            $stmt->bindValue($key, $vals[$i], PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
        } else {
            $stmt->bindValue($key, $vals[$i]);
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $stmt->bindValue('id', $this->Id());

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the same error.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found the answer:

My mistake was that I was trying to typecast to booleans/integers which didn't work on empty strings. So I had to filter the empty strings themselves as well and cast them directly to null values. So, the above binding foreach loop should look like this instead:

```
foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if($key === 'g_exists' && $vals[$i] === '') { // filter key AND empty value
            $stmt->bindValue($key, $vals[$i], PDO::PARAM_NULL); // cast to null
        } else {
            $stmt->bindValue($key, $vals[$i]);
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating "the setting part" of the query in a loop irregardless of whether there are any values to write or not.

So the solution would be to check whether there is a value for given key.

A simple solution might me to call `array_filter` on the array containing the data - this way the [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) values and their keys are being removed before processing

Try to start the method like this:

```
public function updateMod($array)
{
    $array = array_filter($array); # This line is important
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $vals = array_values($array);

    ...
```

[`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) documentations says:

> If no callback is supplied, all empty entries of array will be removed

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't want to remove these fields from the array, I do want them to be processed. The user of the application should be able to delete the last input entry of a field and then leave that field empty. Therefore, I need the update method to be able to enter null entries into the database. But filtering the array before and changing the empty inputs to 'null' didn't help either, because (I suppose) through the pdo binding these nulls got translated into 'null' strings again and were then not recognized correctly by Postgres.

Comment: While writing that comment, the answer got clear to me: I should try to type cast to null, but not before the binding process but within the process. And it worked! (See my answer on that)

Comment: @Nana Good to hear that